# iOS - Customize Navigation Bar for only some UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

I have to add new screens to an existing app, that will use a different navigation bar style than the one that already exists and will be accessed from different screens. The idea would be to show the new Navigation Bar style only for those screens, so when the user finishes that flow or goes back to the screen that started the navigation, it should show again the navigation bar style it was previously using.

I have tried 2 things but didn't work as expected:

1. I thought of wrapping the new screens in a new `UINavigationController`, so I could change its navigation bar style and it would be consistent for the new screens. It works but the problem is that I am not able to customize the initial `UINavigationController` transition to make it not look like a modal (i.e I want to show that `UINavigationController` with the same animation as if I were pushing a `UIViewController`). Is there a way to do that? By the way, I am managing the navigations with storyboards segues.
2. I also thought of using

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
```

But doesn't seem clean because I would have to show it again when the flow is finished (it is a bit long) or cancelled. This makes a lot of combinations and it would be easy to miss one of them, so this doesn't seem a practical solution. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `presenting view controller` is where you want to change the nav bar for the controller to be presented. So you'd make any changes to the navbar just before you call `push(viewController:animated:)`.

And then in `viewWillAppear` of still the `presenting view controller` you would reset the navbar to what it was initially.

***NOTE:** Keep in mind that depending on the kind of changes you're doing to the navbar, the transition might no longer be smooth. The user might see some flickering of sorts on the navbar, which would be poor UI/UX.*

***Edit: Another alternative***

Alternatively, you could get rid of the navbar and instead implement your own `header view` that you can style however you want, to represent the navbar.

- You can style it as a simple navbar with a title + back button.
- You can style it to look like a navbar with large title
- You can style it as a navbar with back button + background image + title + right bar buttons

As you can see, this second alternative offers you more freedom in what you can do.

Comment: That is a part of what I described in step 2 of my question. It is a valid approach but doesn't seem too clean for me. I was asking if there is a better option that doesn't involver changing styles every time a screen is presented and dismissed.

Comment: You could implement your own navbar view. So instead of the actual navbar, you have a `header view` that you can style as you want. You could have a `header view` with just a back button and title. Another `header view` could have back button, background image + title, styled to look like navbar with large titles...this will offer you more flexibility

Comment: This has to be integrated with an existing nav controller that has its own styles, so to customize that nav bar I would basically have to know what view controllers use one style and what other use a different one. I am trying to avoid that (read what I mentioned in option #1 in my question), but in the end it maybe the only solution.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way of achieving what you want, but you could try either creating a base controller that other controllers extend. This base controller would then have the new navbar functionality, so you don't have to make too many changes. Alternatively, you could use a protocol instead